# SELECT distinct top 5 Topic_ID, Thread_ID from tblThread ORDER BY Thread_ID DESC

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to return the latest 5 topics with threads in from the Threads table. I also then need to join the topic table to return topic_name + from the thread table join to the author table and return author name.

If a topic appears a number of times in the most recent x posts I only want the most recent (highest) thread id info.

```
SELECT distinct top 5 Topic_ID, Thread_ID from tblThread ORDER BY Thread_ID DESC
```

just returns the 5 most recent thread ID's as follows

topic_id - Thread_id

852 - 2905

852 - 2904,

850 - 2903,

937 - 2902,

937 - 2901

I want to return
852 - 2905 + other fields, topic name, author name

850 - 2903 + ..

937 - 2902 + ...

& next two topic id's

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your should probably grab the corresponding Thread ID's with a GROUP BY on the topic, and MAX on thread ID, sorting by thread ID DESC, and limiting to 5. Then query the threads with their ID IN the previous set. Sorry I don't have time to create a working query, it is just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick (though you need to use your real tables and columns there):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Topic_ID ORDER BY Thread_ID DESC) RN
    FROM tblThread 
)
SELECT  A.Topic_ID,
        A.Thread_ID,
        B.Topic_Name,
        C.Author_Name
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN tblTopic B
    ON A.Topic_ID = B.Topic_ID
INNER JOIN tblAuthor C
    ON A.Author_ID = C.Author_ID
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Hi Lamak, no idea how you came up with that but it works with proper table names, fields order by :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work:

```
select topic, max(thread) as thread from tblThread
group by topic
order by thread desc
```

You would do whatever joins you need after that.

Comment: Thanks.When I padded this out to:

Comment: SELECT top 5 tblThread.Topic_ID, Max(tblThread.Thread_ID) AS ThreadID, tblTopic.Subject
FROM (tblThread INNER JOIN tblTopic ON tblThread.Topic_ID = tblTopic.Topic_ID) INNER JOIN tblAuthor ON tblThread.Author_ID = tblAuthor.Author_ID
GROUP BY tblThread.Topic_ID, tblTopic.Subject
ORDER BY ThreadID DESC;

Comment: It returns correctly but no author name. when I add ", tblAuthor.Username" to the first line I get the error "Column 'tblAuthor.Username' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." butg when I add it to the group by I get incorrect results. Any ideas?

Comment: Take this and use it as a derived table that you then join to your main table: select Username from (select topic, max(thread) ...) t inner join tblAuthor a on t.topic = a.topic ...

Answer (score 0):

final answer:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT top 10 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Topic_ID ORDER BY Thread_ID DESC) RN
    FROM tblThread 
    ORDER BY tblThread.Thread_ID DESC
)
SELECT  tblThread.Topic_ID,
        tblThread.Thread_ID,
        tblTopic.Subject,
        tblAuthor.UserName
FROM CTE tblThread
INNER JOIN tblTopic
    ON tblThread.Topic_ID = tblTopic.Topic_ID
INNER JOIN tblAuthor
    ON tblThread.Author_ID = tblAuthor.Author_ID
WHERE RN = 1
```